# How to determine Docker version

Tags: docker

When I run:

```
$ docker -v
```

the output is:

```
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

What version they mean when the write

> If you use Docker 1.13 or higher, use --cpus instead.

Asking because the difference between 18 and 1 is too big to me. Can the docu be so old? Or do the docker versions increase so fast?

Comment: it's something like this, they have upgraded their versions quickly ! 
v17.12, v17.09, v17.06, v17.03, v1.13, v1.12, v1.11,  v1.10, v1.9, v1.8, v1.7, v1.6, v1.5, v1.4 ....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`docker -v` only shows the client version. `docker version` will show both client and server version. [1.13](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-engine/) wasn't that long ago, docker just decided to jump their version numbers rapidly.

Comment: docker version - gives all the version info but 
To get only the server version details, we can run docker version --format '{{.Server.Version}}'

Comment: docker version --format '{{.Client.Version}}' to get docker client version  info